# Unable to get Jetty HelloWorld example to work

Tags: java, eclipse, embedded-jetty

Edit: It appears that this problem may be localized to the version of javax.servlet I'm using. I got 2.5 from the site and it wasn't working, though using a different version I got from a demo project my prof published, it seems to work. Not sure exactly which version it is though.

---

Using the following code from https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld, I seem to be getting nowhere, and I have no idea why...

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class HelloWorld extends AbstractHandler
{
    public void handle(String target,
                       Request baseRequest,
                       HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(new HelloWorld());

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

I've downloaded the two jar files it says to, and compiled and ran the program with the following:

```
Q:\Documents\Development\Eclipse\3715a5\src>javac -cp "..\lib\*;." HelloWorld.java
Q:\Documents\Development\Eclipse\3715a5\src>java -cp "..\lib\*;." HelloWorld
```

I have the following output on my standard output when I run:

```
2014-03-18 00:09:57.825:INFO::main: Logging initialized @89ms
2014-03-18 00:09:57.872:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.3.v20140225
2014-03-18 00:09:57.913:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@edd9de{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2014-03-18 00:09:57.915:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @182ms
```

But when I use any web browser to browse to `http://localhost:8080`, I get nothing. I try using putty to connect to localhost:8080 via telnet, and I get "Software cause connection abort". I've disabled my windows firewall just to be certain, and I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: Try another port number

Comment: @ray i tried port 8000 to no avail

Comment: I tried with the eclipse IDE and it is working for me. what all jar files you have in your lib folder?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be related to the version of javax.servlet I was using. I downloaded version 2.5 from the linked website, and since tried a different version (not sure which one) that was given to me by my prof for this assignment, and it is working.

Comment: thanks agent154, i switched to 3.1 and helloworld starts working for me now

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Server serverJetty = new Server();

SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(jettyPort);
connector.setHost(jettyHost);
serverJetty.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });
```

Comment: What is jettyPort and jettyHost?

Comment: Try jettyPort=8080 and jettyHost=127.0.0.1

Comment: Looks like the problem is localized to my desktop, as the exact code I pasted above works on my laptop. I'd like to figure out why this is.